# integrate.net framework 4.6 project as windows services

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows-services, localhost

Is there a way to have a .net framework 4.6 project running as a windows service?

I searched on the internet for a solution but all i saw was implementations for .net core, WCF service or .net service application projects.

We use a project in visual studio with .net framework 4.6 for opening a local host. This local host would then be used to startup a website of another project.
We wanted to integrate the local host project as a windows service on a server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio to create a Windows Service project:
[image: Service Project]
There you can also select the framework version to use. My VS 2017 lets me select up to 4.7.1 at the moment. In that service you can then implement your logic to start up the host.